# understanding the semantics of annotating another annotation definition in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Looking at Spring framework annotations, definitions of some (say, annotation A) are themselves annotated by other annotation (say, annotation B). For example:

@RestController definition is annotated by @Controller as seen [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html).

**Question1)** What is the purpose of such annotation?

**Question2)** Suppose, I want to handle such annotations by myself in code; if I read the annotation of a class annotated with B (@RestController), java will return A(@Controller) as well?

Answer (score 1):

As documentation says:

> A convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody.
>   Types that carry this annotation are treated as controllers where @RequestMapping methods assume @ResponseBody semantics by default.

You can use these annotations separately to achieve the same effect.

I assume because so many people so often called both of them they decided to add it out of laziness :)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is mainly readability and DRY (don't repeat yourself, ie. avoiding duplication of declarations).

Spring calls them meta-annotations or composed annotations. Note that they are a Spring feature and **not** present or supported in plain Java, e.g. using Java's annotation reflection features.

Spring has written it's own reflection utilities to be able to support the meta-annotations.
See [their wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Annotation-Programming-Model) and the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html) for some more infos and background.